# Auto scale image height with React Native

Tags: react-native

In my React Native app, I am fetching images from an API with unknown dimensions. How do I auto scale the height if I know my desired width?

Example:

I set the width to `Dimensions.get('window').width`. How do set the height and keep the same ratio?

```js
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      imgUrl: 'http://someimg.com/coolstuff.jpg'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // sets the image url to state
    this.props.getImageFromAPi()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image 
          source={uri: this.state.imgUrl}
          style={styles.myImg}
        />
        <Text>Some description</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
  myImg: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: >>>???what goes here???<<<
  }
)
```

Comment: Have a look at [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image)

Comment: Take a look at react-native-auto-height-image

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Try this:

```js
 import React, { Component, PropTypes } from "react";
 import { Image } from "react-native";

export default class ScaledImage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { source: { uri: this.props.uri } };
}

componentWillMount() {
    Image.getSize(this.props.uri, (width, height) => {
        if (this.props.width && !this.props.height) {
            this.setState({
                width: this.props.width,
                height: height * (this.props.width / width)
            });
        } else if (!this.props.width && this.props.height) {
            this.setState({
                width: width * (this.props.height / height),
                height: this.props.height
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({ width: width, height: height });
        }
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <Image
            source={this.state.source}
            style={{ height: this.state.height, width: this.state.width }}
        />
    );
}
}

ScaledImage.propTypes = {
uri: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
width: PropTypes.number,
height: PropTypes.number
};
```

I'm passing the URL as a prop called `uri`. You can specify your `width` prop as `Dimensions.get('window').width` and that should cover it.

Note that this will also work if you know what you want to set the height to and you need to resize the width to maintain the ratio. In that case, you would specify the `height` prop instead of the `width` one.

Comment: This works, thank you very much. It's surprising to me that there is not a build in method for accomplishing this. I guess RN is still pretty new.

Comment: @plmok61 You could also try the `resizeMode` prop in the `Image` class and applying a `flex` in your styles. I initially tried this, but I didn't like how the container's height would not expand based on the image rescaling.

Comment: Were to add the actual path of the image url?

Comment: @Somename Pass it to the `uri` prop.

Comment: Sorry, im new to RN. Still not able to understand. Read the documentation many times. Please explain where does the actual network url go. Many thanks.

Comment: I tried: `return (
            <Image source={{uri:myImage4}} style={{height: this.state.height, width: this.state.width}}/>
        );`
Where `myImage4` is `var myImage4='http://theSourceOfImage.com'` But its not working.

Comment: @Somename have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image

Comment: ‘Import PropTypes from ‘prop-types’;

Answer (score 54):

There is a property **resizeMode** set it to 'contain'

Example:

```
<Image
    source={require('./local_path_to/your_image.png')}
    style={{ width: 30 }}
    resizeMode="contain"
 />
```

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#resizemode

**Edit:** The above solution is working fine for me, the **resizeMode** property is not deprecated and I couldn't find any indications that they are planning to do so. If for some reason the the above solution doesn't work for you, you can calculate the height yourself. Here is an axample:

```
const Demo = () => {
    const scaleHeight = ({ source, desiredWidth }) => {
        const { width, height } = Image.resolveAssetSource(source)

        return desiredWidth / width * height
    }

    const imageSource = './local_image.png'
    const imageWidth = 150
    const imageHeigh = scaleHeight({
        source: require(imageSource),
        desiredWidth: imageWidth
    })
    
    return (
        <View style={{
            display: 'flex',
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
        }}>
            <Image
                source={require(imageSource)}
                style={{
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    width: imageWidth,
                    height: imageHeigh
                }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

The above solution works only for local images. Here is how to do the same for remote images:

```
const RemoteImage = ({uri, desiredWidth}) => {
    const [desiredHeight, setDesiredHeight] = React.useState(0)

    Image.getSize(uri, (width, height) => {
        setDesiredHeight(desiredWidth / width * height)
    })

    return (
        <Image
            source={{uri}}
            style={{
                borderWidth: 1,
                width: desiredWidth,
                height: desiredHeight
            }}
        />
    )
}

const Demo = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
        }}>
            <RemoteImage
                uri="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"
                desiredWidth={200}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: this solution doesnt work for "expo": "^32.0.0", "react": "16.5.0", "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz", setting height only works, but setting width only in style gives a blank image.

Comment: It does however autoscale the image to fit a defined size, which could help solve the above problem with a bit of thought - certainly helped me with my images of unknown dimensions.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working with the latest version

Comment: @Shivam, I've checked it today and it is working fine. I updated my answer with sample of other approach to the problem. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Underdog you "expo" and "react" versions does not matter. As for "react-native", I checked today and the **resizeMode** property is not deprecated and there are no indications that they are planning to do so.

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov okay so I was trying the remote image.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at this library [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image). It does exactly what you are asking for.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Image from 'react-native-scalable-image';

const image = (
   <Image
       width={Dimensions.get('window').width} // height will be calculated automatically
       source={{uri: '<image uri>'}}
   />
);
```

Comment: Just tried to use this ~2022 and it hasn't been updated for 2 years + meaning the dependencies no longer resolve for latest React 17x

Answer (score 7):

I created a hook that calculates an image's aspect ratio:

```js
function useImageAspectRatio(imageUrl) {
  const [aspectRatio, setAspectRatio] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!imageUrl) {
      return;
    }

    let isValid = true;
    Image.getSize(imageUrl, (width, height) => {
      if (isValid) {
        setAspectRatio(width / height);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      isValid = false;
    };
  }, [imageUrl]);

  return aspectRatio;
}
```

With that you can set only one value of width or height, and calculate the other automatically:

```js
function App() {
  const aspectRatio = useImageAspectRatio(imageUrl);

  return (
    <Image 
      src={{ uri: imageUrl }}
      style={{ width: 200, aspectRatio }}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Hooks version of @**TheJizel** answer. I knew the width but wanted the height of the image, so the below worked for me :

```
    const ScaledImage = props => {

    const [width, setWidth] = useState()
    const [height, setHeight] = useState()
    const [imageLoading, setImageLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        Image.getSize(props.uri, (width1, height1) => {
            if (props.width && !props.height) {
                setWidth(props.width)
                setHeight(height1 * (props.width / width1))
            } else if (!props.width && props.height) {
                setWidth(width1 * (props.height / height1))
                setHeight(props.height)
            } else {
                setWidth(width1)
                setHeight(height1)
            }
            setImageLoading(false)
        }, (error) => {
            console.log("ScaledImage,Image.getSize failed with error: ", error)
        })
    }, [])


    return (
        height ?
            <View style={{ height: height, width: width, borderRadius: 5, backgroundColor: "lightgray" }}>
                <Image
                    source={{ uri: props.uri }}
                    style={{ height: height, width: width, borderRadius: 5, }}
                />
            </View>
            : imageLoading ?
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
                : null
    );
}
```

Usage :

```
<ScaledImage width={Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.8} uri={imageurl} />
```

Answer (score 5):

**TypeScript** version of @TheJizel answer with optional `style` property and `failure` callback in `Image.getSize`:

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import {Image} from 'react-native'

interface Props {
    uri: string
    width?: number
    height?: number
    style?
}

interface State {
    source: {}
    width: number
    height: number
}

export default class ScaledImage extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            source: {uri: this.props.uri},
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        Image.getSize(this.props.uri, (width, height) => {
            if (this.props.width && !this.props.height) {
                this.setState({width: this.props.width, height: height * (this.props.width / width)})
            } else if (!this.props.width && this.props.height) {
                this.setState({width: width * (this.props.height / height), height: this.props.height})
            } else {
                this.setState({width: width, height: height})
            }
        }, (error) => {
            console.log("ScaledImage:componentWillMount:Image.getSize failed with error: ", error)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <Image source={this.state.source} style={[this.props.style, {height: this.state.height, width: this.state.width}]}/>
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```js
<ScaledImage style={styles.scaledImage} uri={this.props.article.coverImageUrl} width={Dimensions.get('window').width}/>
```

Answer (score 3):

First try this and see if it works for you: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/5850165795c54b8d5de7bef9f69f6fe6b1b4763d

If it doesn't, then you can implement your own image component. But instead of taking width as prop, you override `onLayout` method which gives you desired width so that you can calculate the height. This works better if you don't know the width and want RN to do the layout for you. The drawback is `onLayout` is called after one pass of layout and rendering. So you might notice your components moving around a bit.

Comment: after all,... implement your own component is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answers above, I made, with **TypeScript**, a functional component that downloads the image only once (because the second time it will be cached: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#getsize), if only one value is passed; and that calculates both height and width, depending on the property that was passed

```js
    import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import React from 'react';
    import { ImageProps, ImageURISource } from 'react-native';
    import { useIsMounted } from '../../hooks/is-mounted';
    import { DrImageStyl } from './styled';
    import { getImageSizes } from '../../utils/util';
    
    interface DrSource extends ImageURISource {
      uri: string;
    }
    
    interface DrImageProps extends ImageProps {
      source: DrSource;
      width?: number;
      height?: number;
    }
    
    const DrImage: React.FC<DrImageProps> = ({
      width: widthProp,
      height: heightProp,
      source,
      ...rest
    }: DrImageProps) => {
      const isMountedRef = useIsMounted();
    
      const [sizes, setSizes] = React.useState({
        width: widthProp,
        height: heightProp,
      });
    
      useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
          const getImageSizesState = async () => {
            try {
              const { width, height } = await getImageSizes({
                uri: source.uri,
                width: widthProp,
                height: heightProp,
              });
    
              if (isMountedRef.current) {
                setSizes({ width, height });
              }
            } catch (error) {
              console.log('Erro em dr-image getImageSizesState:', error);
            }
          };
    
          getImageSizesState();
        }, [widthProp, heightProp, source.uri])
      );
    
      return (
        <>
          {!!sizes.height && !!sizes.width && (
            <DrImageStyl sizes={sizes} source={source} {...rest} />
          )}
        </>
      );
    };

export default DrImage;
```

I used a hook to determine if, after the asynchronous function, the component is still mounted (**useIsMounted**):

```js
import React from 'react';

export const useIsMounted = (): React.MutableRefObject<boolean> => {
  const isMountedRef = React.useRef(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    isMountedRef.current = true;
    return () => {
      isMountedRef.current = false;
    };
  }, []);
  return isMountedRef;
};
```

I used the styled-components module to make the component's css (**DrImageStyl** ):

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components/native';

interface Sizes {
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
}

interface DrImageStylProps {
  sizes: Sizes;
}

export const DrImageStyl = styled.Image<DrImageStylProps>`
  ${({ sizes }) => {
    const { width, height } = sizes;

    return css`
      ${width ? `width: ${width}px;` : ''}
      ${height ? `height: ${height}px;` : ''}
    `;
  }}
`;
```

I separated the code that calculates the other image size (**getImageSizes**):

```js
import { Image } from 'react-native';

interface GetImageSizesParams {
  uri: string;
  height?: number;
  width?: number;
}

export function getImageSizes({
  height: heightParam,
  width: widthParam,
  uri,
}: GetImageSizesParams): Promise<{
  width: number;
  height: number;
}> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    function onSuccess(width: number, height: number) {
      let widthResolve: number | undefined;
      let heightResolve: number | undefined;

      if (widthParam && !heightParam) {
        widthResolve = widthParam;
        heightResolve = height * (widthParam / width);
      } else if (!widthParam && heightParam) {
        widthResolve = width * (heightParam / height);
        heightResolve = heightParam;
      } else {
        widthResolve = widthParam;
        heightResolve = heightParam;
      }

      resolve({
        width: widthResolve as number,
        height: heightResolve as number,
      });
    }

    function onError(error: any) {
      reject(error);
    }
    try {
      Image.getSize(uri, onSuccess, onError);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please highlight what makes your approach notable given the pre-existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use any lib to achieve this instead use the below solution:

```
import React from  'react';
import { ImageProps } from 'react-native';
import FastImage from "react-native-fast-image";

const AutoHeightImage = React.memo(function AutoHeightImage ({ width,imageStyle, ...props }: ImageProps) {
  const [state, setstate] = React.useState(0)
  return (
    <FastImage 
      {...props}
      style={[{ width: width, height: state }, imageStyle]}
      resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
      onLoad={(evt) => {
        setstate((evt.nativeEvent.height / evt.nativeEvent.width) * width)
      }}
    />
  )
})

export default AutoHeightImage;
```

**How to use the above custom component:**

```
 <AutoHeightImage
     width={(Dimensions.get('window').width)}
     source={{ uri: 'image url' }}/>
```

React native fast image used from https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image

Comment: react-native-fast-image is a library?

Comment: @owenmelbz yes it is library

Comment: I see, sorry for misunderstanding as you said:

No need to use any lib to achieve this instead use the below solution:

Comment: Yes @owenmelbz you can use <Image instead of FastImage. i just put example how i achieve that with custom class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a gist for a pretty simple solution that leverages  [@Haitao Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377258/haitao-li)'s proposal to use aspectRatio:

https://gist.github.com/tpraxl/02dc4bfcfa301340d26a0bf2140cd8b9

No magic and no calculations necessary. Pure "CSS" if you know the original image's dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution works, but you have to download image twice, once to determine the size and another to actually show the image, this is a different approach, image is loaded squared initially and resized.

```
import React, { Component, } from "react";
import { Image } from "react-native";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

    export default class ScaledImage extends Component {
        state = {}

        componentWillMount() {
            const { uri, width, height } = this.props;
            this.setState({ source: { uri }, width: width || height, height: height || width });
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <Image
                    source={this.state.source}
                    onLoad={(value) => {
                        const { height, width } = value.nativeEvent.source;
                        if (this.props.width && !this.props.height) {
                            this.setState({
                                width: this.props.width,
                                height: height * (this.props.width / width)
                            });
                        } else if (!this.props.width && this.props.height) {
                            this.setState({
                                width: width * (this.props.height / height),
                                height: this.props.height
                            });
                        } else {
                            this.setState({ width: width, height: height });
                        }

                    }}
                    style={{ height: this.state.height, width: this.state.width }}
                />
            );
        }
    }

    ScaledImage.propTypes = {
        uri: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        width: PropTypes.number,
        height: PropTypes.number
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 numbers :

1. width  of Image
2. height of Image
3. width  of Screen

and you should put "width  of Screen" in width style and also calculate 
height for setup in style ??!!

```
componentWillMount() {

    Image.getSize(this.props.product.image, (width, height) => {

        const screenWidth = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width);  
        this.setState({screenWidth:screenWidth});
        Calculatedheight = screenWidth * height / width ;
        this.setState({Calculatedheight : Calculatedheight });

    });

}
```

and

```
<Image
  source={{uri: product.image,cache: 'only-if-cached'}}
  style={{ height: this.state.screenHeight , width: this.state.Calculatedheight }}

/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me in expo

```
<Image style={{flex:1,width:null,height:null }} resizeMode={'contain'}  source={{uri: 'http://134.209.40.60/meApunto/1567655610795_1944474896.png'}}></Image>
```

https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-fit-a-big-image-into-a-fixed-container-without-resizemode-help/27639

Comment: @miteshkalal I think this is expo specific, if you are new to react native, take a look at flutter, this is going to be the future.

Comment: no i am not new in react-native. what happens with react-native in future.

Comment: Use undefined instead of null

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
 <Image source={{ uri }} style={{width:"100%", height:'100%'}} 
 resizeMode='contain'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @TheJizel's idea, I cooked up something using the aspectRatio style property. The following class works when the width is set, but height is omitted. This also works with percentages as width.

```
import React from "react";
import { Image } from "react-native";

export default class ScaledImage extends React.Component {

  state = {
    aspectRatio: 0
  }

  setAspectRatio(ratio) {
    this.setState({
      aspectRatio: ratio
    });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (Array.isArray(this.props.source)) {
      console.warn("ScaledImage received an array as source instead of local file resource or ImageURISource.")
    } else if(typeof this.props.source === "number") {
      // Resolve local file resource
      const resolved = Image.resolveAssetSource(this.props.source);

      // We assume 100% width, so we set the aspect ratio we want for it's height
      this.setAspectRatio(resolved.width / resolved.height);

    } else if (this.props.source.uri) {
      // Resolve remote resource
      Image.getSize(this.props.source.uri, (width, height) => {
         this.setAspectRatio( width / height);
      }, (err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });

    } else {
      console.warn("ScaledImage did not receive a valid source uri.");
    }
  }

  render() {
    if(!this.state.aspectRatio) return null;

    const props = {
      ...this.props,
      style: [this.props.style, {
        aspectRatio: this.state.aspectRatio
      }]
    };

    return (
      <Image {...props} />
    )
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<ScaledImage source={{ uri: "<URI HERE>" }} style={{ width: "100%" }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I'm using in production.  The backend user could make a logo image of any size and aspect ratio, but I needed the logo to fit an exact height with a max width.  My self-scaling component is what resulted:

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect, SFC } from "react";
import { Image } from "react-native";
import { Spinner } from "native-base";


interface INetworkImage {
    targetHeight: number,
    uri: string,
    maxWidth: number
}

const NetworkImage: SFC<INetworkImage> = ({ uri, targetHeight, maxWidth }) => {

    useLayoutEffect(() => setNaturalDimensions(uri), []);

    const [imageWidth, setWidth] = useState(0);
    const [imageHeight, setHeight] = useState(0);
    const [scaleFactor, setScale] = useState(1);

    function setNaturalDimensions(uri: string) {
        Image.getSize(uri, (width: number, height: number) => {
            if (width > maxWidth) {
                // too wide case
                setScale(maxWidth / width);
            } else {
                // scale to height case
                setScale(targetHeight / height);
            }
            setWidth(width);
            setHeight(height);
        }, (error: any) => {
            console.log("error", error);
        });
    }
    function adjustView(e) {
        if (e.nativeEvent.layout.width > maxWidth) {
            setScale(scaleFactor * (maxWidth/e.nativeEvent.layout.width));
        }
    }
    return (
        imageHeight ?
        <Image
            onLayout={(e) => adjustView(e)}
            source={{ uri: uri }}
            style={{
                width: imageWidth * scaleFactor,
                height: imageHeight * scaleFactor,
                resizeMode: "contain",
            }}
        />:
        <Spinner color='#454c7a' />
        );
}
export default NetworkImage;
```

Then I use it by passing the uri, targetHeight, and maxwidth in as props:

```
export const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;

<NetworkImage
    uri={"https://purdyPic.com/image1"}
    targetHeight={300}
    maxWidth={deviceWidth * 0.85}
                          />
```

Answer (score 0):

one solution out of many

```
<Image source={...} style={{ transform: [{ scale: 0.5 }] }} />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

So this all helped me a bunch

My particular scenario involved getting images from a server that could be either portrait or landscape, and I needed to fit them into a `<View>`.

This means the "known" dimensions are of that view, which I obtained via `onLayout` (simplified code to just show an example setting a "height"):

```html
<View onLayout={(event) => setCellHeight(event.nativeEvent.layout.height)}>
```

Now with my known `displayAreaHeight` and `displayAreaWidth` values I need to size my image:

```ts
  // Set image size for portrait/landscape scenarios, reducing the total image size when
  // an overflow of the display area would occur.

  if (image.height > image.width) { // Portrait Image
    const ratio = displayAreaHeight / image.height;
    imageHeight = displayAreaHeight;
    imageWidth = image.width * ratio;
    if (imageWidth > displayAreaWidth) {
      const heightReductionRatio = displayAreaWidth / imageWidth;
      imageHeight *= heightReductionRatio;
      imageWidth = displayAreaWidth;
    }
  } else {
    const ratio = displayAreaWidth / image.width;
    imageHeight = image.height * ratio;
    imageWidth = displayAreaWidth;
    if (imageHeight > displayAreaHeight) {
      const widthReductionRatio = displayAreaHeight / imageHeight;
      imageWidth *= widthReductionRatio;
      imageHeight = displayAreaHeight;
    }
  }
```

Hopefully this, along with all the other great responses here, helps someone out

Answer (score 0):

here is functional component sollution for using local files:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-native';
import resolveAssetSource from 'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource';

const ScaledImage = props => {
  const [source, setSource] = useState(props.uri);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(props.width);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(props.height);

  useEffect(() => {
    let dimensions = resolveAssetSource(source);
    if (props.width && !props.height) {
      setWidth(props.width);
      setHeight(dimensions.height * (props.width / dimensions.width));
    } else if (!props.width && props.height) {
      setWidth(dimensions.width * (props.height / dimensions.height));
      setHeight(props.height);
    } else {
      setWidth(dimensions.width);
      setHeight(dimensions.height);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Image
      source={source}
      style={[{height: height, width: width}, props.style]}
    />
  );
};

export default ScaledImage;
```

usage example:

```
<ScaledImage
  width={Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.8}
  uri={require('../../../images/Logo_Poziom.png')}
  style={[
    {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 100,
      zIndex: 1,
    },
  ]}
/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to scale the image automatically also wish to apply the default image when the image is in the rendering process use this

```
import ScalableImage from 'react-native-scalable-image';
```

here combined is variable in witch API response is saved and large_image is variable which contain image address and ImageURL variable contain image base path

```
 for (let i = 0; i < combined.length; i++) {
            Image.getSize(
              ImageURL + combined[i].large_image,
              (width, height) => {
                combined[i].imageSize = {
                  'ImageHeight': (height).toString(),
                  'ImageWidth': (width).toString(),
                };
              },
            );
          }
```

this is how we show image with default image with different height and width without cropping

```
 <ImageBackground
                          source={require('../Assets/Icons/thumbnail.png')}
                          style={{
                            width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                            height: undefined,
                            aspectRatio:item?.imageSize? item?.imageSize?.ImageWidth / item?.imageSize?.ImageHeight : 1
                          }}>
                          <ScalableImage
                            width={Dimensions.get('window').width}
                            source={{uri: ImageURL + item.large_image}}
                          />
                        </ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `Image.getSize`

```js
const [height, setHeight] = useState(startingHeight || 260);
const desiredWidth = 500;

useEffect(() => {
  Image.getSize(path, (width, height) => setHeight((desiredWidth / width) * height));
}, [path]);

  <Image
    source={{ uri: path }}
    style={{ height }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the resolution of the image, you can use this simple logic:

```
<Image
  style={{
    width: desiredWidth, // 300px in my case
    height: (imageOwnHeight / imageOwnWidth) * desiredWidth,
  }}
  source={require('../../../../assets/mention-info.png')}
/>
```