# Scale image down to device width in React Native ScrollView

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, scrollview

I have an image I'd like to be full width of the device screen.

Using just a View I can achieve this:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
     <Image resizeMode="contain" style={{flex: 1, height: undefined, width: undefined}} source={this.props.images.infoImage} />
</View>
```

Changing this to a ScrollView causes the image to stop rendering completely:

```
<ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
     <Image resizeMode="contain" style={{flex: 1, height: undefined, width: undefined}} source={this.props.images.infoImage} />
</ScrollView>
```

I found that if I set a height on the image it would render...but I want the image to dynamically respond to the size of the device.

How can I solve this without declaring an explicit height?

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170127/auto-scale-image-height-with-react-native/42170351

Comment: Have a look at [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image)

Answer (score 6):

As per @martinarroyo's comment I added `contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}` to the ScrollView, like so:

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}>
    <Image resizeMode="contain" style={{flex: 1, width: undefined, height: undefined}} source={this.props.images.infoImage} />
</ScrollView
```

This completely resolved my issue. The image is the full width of the display while maintaining the correct aspect ratio.

**EDIT:** Turns out the image frame height stays the same but the image scales down. This means it has large chunks of padding on the top and bottom. As of now I don't know how to remove it.

**EDIT 2:**

It seems there aren't any tools out of the box with RN and ultimately ended up using a modified version of @Ihor Burlachenko's solution. I created a custom component that takes desired width/height constraints and scales it based on that. I need to use this for local files, which `Image.getSize()` method does not work on, so I modified Ihor's solution to allow for that by passing in a dimensions object that contain width and height.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';

export default class ScalableImage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            width: null,
            height: null,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if(typeof this.props.source === 'string') {
            Image.getSize(this.props.source, this._calculateImageDimensions, console.log);
        } else if(this.props.dimensions) {
            this._calculateImageDimensions(this.props.dimensions.width, this.props.dimensions.height)
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Image
                { ...this.props }
                style={[
                    this.props.style,
                    { width: this.state.width, height: this.state.height }
                ]}
            />
        );
    }

    _calculateImageDimensions(width, height) {
        let ratio;

        if (this.props.width && this.props.height) {
            ratio = Math.min(this.props.width / width, this.props.height / height);
        }
        else if (this.props.width) {
            ratio = this.props.width / width;
        }
        else if (this.props.height) {
            ratio = this.props.height / height;
        }

        this.setState({ width: width * ratio, height: height * ratio });
    }
}

ScalableImage.propTypes = {
    width: React.PropTypes.number,
    height: React.PropTypes.number,
    dimensions: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

I then use it as so:

```
<ScalableImage source={require('../path/to/local/image.png')} 
               width={Dimensions.get('window').width()} 
               dimensions={{width: 700, height: 400}} />
```

Comment: Hey @callmetwan, If I want to do something like this? how can achieve these? it's a horizontal ScrollView and when the item focused it's scaled or something like this.   https://imgur.com/gaMxyTP

Answer (score 0):

As a last resource, you can use [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html).

Get the windows's width and height on every `render`, that way you'll account for changes in size (basically, rotations) and will match every device.

You can use it like this:

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native'+
// Then, in your component:
render(){
    const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window'):
    return (<ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
     <Image resizeMode="contain" style={{flex: 1, height, width}} source={this.props.images.infoImage} />
</ScrollView>)
}
```

Comment: This will make the image the full height of the device which I'm not looking to do. Essentially I'm looking for the equivalency of how `max-width: 100%` works in the browser.

Comment: Mmm... you are right. Also I noticed that you are not using `contentContainerStyle` in your `<ScrollView>`. Try setting it to `contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}`.

Comment: Adding `contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}` did it!!

Comment: Hey @martinarroyo, If I want to do something like this? how can achieve these? it's a horizontal ScrollView and when the item focused it's scaled or something like this.   https://imgur.com/gaMxyTP

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wrapping React Image inside [custom Image component](https://github.com/ihor/react-native-scalable-image/blob/master/index.js) which calculates height dynamically to keep the image ratio in `onComponentDidMount`:

```
Image.getSize(this.props.source.uri, (width, height) => {
    let ratio;

    if (this.props.width && this.props.height) {
        ratio = Math.min(this.props.width / width, this.props.height / height);
    }
    else if (this.props.width) {
        ratio = this.props.width / width;
    }
    else if (this.props.height) {
        ratio = this.props.height / height;
    }

    this.setState({ width: width * ratio, height: height * ratio });
}, console.log);
```

And then I use it like that:

```
<Image width={Dimensions.get('window').width} source={{uri: '<image uri>'}} />
```

Comment: Hey @IhorBurlachenko, If I want to do something like this? how can achieve these? it's a horizontal ScrollView and when the item focused it's scaled or something like this.   https://imgur.com/gaMxyTP