# Make Image fill parent, but keep ratio in react-native (dynamic/network images)

Tags: react-native, mobile, frontend

I want my image to fit as best as possible into its parent, while keeping its width/height ratio. I fetch the image at runtime, so I don't know the width/height of my images beforehand, so it needs to be dynamic.

In the web I can achieve this with:

```
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

This is how it should look like (simplified):
https://codepen.io/laurentsmohr/pen/OBEGRG?fbclid=IwAR1-dFcTC7vvXwd0m2NTeCMxm6A6Uzv0lFx2UUCNpgFnpSgEm9aHhr14LK4

Comment: Have you tried setting resizeMode to contain to image element with height and width 100%

Comment: @AshwinMothilal yeah. Won't do it. Will not show anything.
If manually set width and height it does, but again, thats not what I want

Comment: @LaurentsMohr , take a look at this , https://stackoverflow.com/a/42170351/2083099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the solutions posted above work for local images, they don't work for network images.
Here is why: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#why-not-automatically-size-everything

The simplest solution for me was to calculate the height off my component based on the Dimensions height and the flex-portion my component takes in the view.
E.g. in my view the image component has a .85 flex, in a parent that has a 1 flex.
So 100% height of the parent equals to:

```
Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.85
```

Answer (score 12):

According to [this official React-Native guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images), if you want to make an image scale dynamically according to its parent element dimensions, you have to set the width and height of the image to undefined, and perhaps also add resizeMode="contain" to the image props.  You can use this following styling to your image:

```js
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native;

// Get device width
const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

/*
image container dimension is dynamic depending on the device width
image will dimension will follow imageContainer's dimension
*/
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageContainer: {
    height: deviceWidth * 0.8,
    width: deviceWidth * 0.8
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    height: undefined,
    width: undefined
  }
});

export default styles;
```

Comment: This might work for static images, but not for dynamic images.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me for a remote image. Although I added resizeMode: 'cover' for good measure. RN 0.60

Comment: I try to use `deviceWidth` in the styles like so and I get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: deviceWidth`

Answer (score 2):

I always use `StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject`. It will fill the parent's size. `resizeMode` can be `contain, cover, stretch, center, repeat`. Like this:

```
  image: {
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It won't show the image at all. The image is a network image, I might add. Not a local one

Answer (score 0):

This styling works for me:

```
 image: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "contain",
  },
```

:shipit:

Answer (score 0):

React Next set up for an image that fills its parent container:

```html
  image={
          <Image
            src="https://picsum.photos/1174/611?random=65411"
            alt="mandatory alt text goes here"
            quality={100}
            layout="fill"
          />
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the image resizeMode which can either be - contain, cover, stretch, center, repeat, will do the trick

```
 <Image
     alt="image Not find"
     source={require("./path/to/image.jpeg")}
     style={{resizeMode: 'contain' }}
 />
```