# How to resize image with React Native ? Why is it so complicated?

Tags: react-native

My original image measures `1080` (w) * `607` (h). It comes from a server (not from local). The dimensions are not supposed to be known (I have a lot of image with different dimensions).

I *simply* want my image to be fully visible on my device, respecting the ratio.

I tried to display this image in `resizeMode : contain`  with a `width: 100%`. It displays very well, but with a big huge margin (I added a red background to realize this). I don't understand this margin.

```
return (
  ...
    <Image
      source={{ uri: http://... }}
      containerStyle={[
        styles.image_container
      ]}
      resizeMode="contain"
    />
  ....
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    image_container: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: '100%',
    aspectRatio: 1
  },
)}
```

[image]

I think it's because of `aspectRatio: 1`. **But if I remove `aspectRatio: 1` the image is hidden.** I tried a lot of combination with `width` / `height` / `aspectRatio`.

I searched a lot (a lot a lot) on google but this question often returns a ton of possibility (with lot of calculs ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170127/auto-scale-image-height-with-react-native))) and no universal answer.

I think my situation is the simplest but it seems so complicated it gets weird.

Comment: Have you tried a calculated `aspectRatio` like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631895/how-to-set-image-width-to-be-100-and-height-to-be-auto-in-react-native#56784685)? I can not check now but seems to be something that is simple & working.

Comment: @Gaylord.P please consider awarding bounty if my answer helped you. Your reputation spent on bounty will not come back to you even if you don't award the bounty to anyone. https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const [width, setWidth] = useState();
const [height, setHeight] = useState();
const win = Dimensions.get('window');
Image.getSize(myUri, (width, height) => {setWidth(width); setHeight(height)});
const a = 0.5;

const App = () => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Image source={myUri} style={styles.image}>
    </View>
  )

}

const styles = Stylesheet.create({
  image: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    width: a * win.width,
    height: (a * win.width)*(height/width),
  }
})
```

Here we are using the width of the screen to determine what should be the optimum width of the image. You can vary the value of `a` in order to set desired width %. `height` is calculated to maintain the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: Why not just a constant `width`% and a calculated `aspectRatio`?

Comment: @DávidLaczkó That depends on the user. The code I wrote provides flexibility to change width%

Comment: I see, but for the specific question it seems a little bit overcomplicated. A simple solution as the OP asked could be one I linked under the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image)

```
yarn add react-native-scalable-image
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Image from 'react-native-scalable-image';

const image = (
   <Image
       width={Dimensions.get('window').width} // height will be calculated automatically
       source={{uri: '<image uri>'}}
   />
);
```