# Why React Native <Image /> has wrong aspect ratio when height isn't auto?

Tags: react-native, image, react-native-image

React Native `<Image />` doesn't display correctly when `width: "100%"`. Well, it displays but with wrong aspect ratio, even if I have specified the correct one. It ignores `aspectRatio` property unless I put `height: "auto"`.

It looks like it happens only with local images. And it's the same for both Android and Web.

My code:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  img: { width: "100%" }
})

// Doesn't display properly
<Image
  source={require("./local-img.webp")}
  style={{ ...styles.img, aspectRatio: 646 / 1064 }}
/>

// Displays properly
<Image
  source={require("./local-img.webp")}
  style={{ ...styles.img, height: "auto", aspectRatio: 646 / 1064 }}
/>

// Displays properly
<Image
  source={{ uri: "https://online-img.webp" }}
  style={{ ...styles.img, aspectRatio: 646 / 1064 }}
/>
```

Expected result:

[image]

Actual result:

[image]

Comment: Does this also happen when using an aspect ratio of `17/28`? I am not sure about the implementation of aspect ratio, but prehaps it might affect the zoom level?

Comment: Yeah, it does. It looks like `aspectRatio` property is totally ignored unless `height: "auto"` is specified.

Comment: Yeah, you must specify a `maxHeight` or `height` for it to work then. Why would that be an issue for you?

Comment: I found the solution but my question is why. Why do I need to do this? Why does `<Image>` require both `width` and `height` to be set even when it's enough to have only `width`/`height` and `aspectRatio`?

Comment: Well, I don't know. It's designed that way probably. Here is something similar i found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631895/how-to-set-image-width-to-be-100-and-height-to-be-auto-in-react-native